# How To add a button to row in a GXT Grid

Tags: gxt

I have a Grid and I want to add a button to each row of the grid and have it reset required data.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using GXT3, here is a link to the Cell Grid example from GXT3.
http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:cellgrid

If you look at the bottom of the page, there are two tabs; one for "Demo" and one for "Source". This demo clearly shows how to add buttons to grids. Take a look at how they are using `TextButtonCell` in the `asWidget()` method.

These examples are a pretty good starting place for figuring out your answers. The next best thing (if you want to figure it out yourself) is to simple navigate the source code.

Hope this helps.